# Cannot interact with jFrame, only plays error note

Tags: java, swing

I been coding on a autoclicker, I just finished but I can't click anything, I can be in the window open but I can't click any button or slider etc.

I am using jnativehook as api for checking mouse press outside.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;

public class AutoClicker extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    public static AutoClicker get = new AutoClicker();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static boolean enabled = false;

//  private MouseHandler mouse;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    public boolean activated;
    public boolean skipNext;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AutoClicker frame = new AutoClicker();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AutoClicker() {
        setTitle("Swezeds AutoClicker");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 403, 253);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.setBounds(88, 36, 89, 23);
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enabled = true;
            }
        });
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.add(btnStart);

        JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
        btnStop.setBounds(187, 36, 89, 23);
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enabled = false;
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnStop);

        JLabel lblSwezedsAutoclicker = new JLabel("Swezeds AutoClicker");
        lblSwezedsAutoclicker.setBounds(102, 11, 167, 14);
        lblSwezedsAutoclicker.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        contentPane.add(lblSwezedsAutoclicker);

        JCheckBox chckbxClickingSound = new JCheckBox("Clicking Sound");
        chckbxClickingSound.setBounds(6, 184, 118, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxClickingSound);

        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setValue(5);
        slider.setMaximum(20);
        slider.setBounds(88, 70, 188, 14);
        contentPane.add(slider);

        JSlider slider_1 = new JSlider();
        slider_1.setMaximum(20);
        slider_1.setValue(12);
        slider_1.setBounds(88, 112, 188, 14);
        contentPane.add(slider_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Max CPS");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(32, 112, 76, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblMinCps = new JLabel("Min CPS");
        lblMinCps.setBounds(32, 70, 76, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblMinCps);

        textField = new JTextField(slider.getValue() + "");
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textField.setBounds(276, 64, 31, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField(slider_1.getValue() + "");
        textField_1.setEditable(false);
        textField_1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(276, 109, 31, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public boolean isSkipNext() {
        return skipNext;
    }

    public void setSkipNext(boolean skipNext) {
        this.skipNext = skipNext;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        AutoClicker.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (;;) {
                Thread.sleep(1L);
                if ((isActivated()) && (isEnabled())) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1L);
                        Robot robot = new Robot();
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                setSkipNext(true);
                                Thread.sleep(AutoClicker.randInt(100, 150));
                                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ecksdee) {
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (AWTException ecksdee) {
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception localException) {
        }
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            this.mouse = new MouseHandler();
            GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(this.mouse);
        } catch (NativeHookException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post code in question as well as error log

Comment: Do not post code as link to an Image. post a [mcve] as text

Comment: Please provide code sample(without external links) and stacktrace that you've got.

Comment: You've overridden `get/setEnabled` which are methods of the `JFrame` which affect the state of the user interaction, so basically, you've disabled the frame.  Suggestion, use a model to manage the state, don't extend directly from `JFrame` (you actually have two different instances running around), use a `JPanel` as the base component and add it what ever window you need when you need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overridden essentially functionality of the `JFrame`

```
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    AutoClicker.enabled = enabled;
}
```

This is changing the user interaction state, basically disabling the frame.

Suggestion, use a model to manage the state, separate the logic from the user interface and share the model between them.

I recommend against using `JFrame` as your primary component, you're not adding any new functionality to the class and it ties you into a single use case.  Better to start with a `JPanel`, then you can add it to whatever container you like.

This:

```
public static AutoClicker get = new AutoClicker();
```

is not how a singleton should be done, besides, you create a whole other instance in the `main` method anyway, so now you run the risk of contaminating the state.  Separating the model/view/controller will help solve part of the problem at least